# Implementing nested/recursive datatypes in the presence of type operators

Tags: haskell, types, lambda-calculus, higher-kinded-types, type-theory

I've been working on my implementation of System F-omega in Rust following Pierce's *Types and Programming Languages*, and I'm looking for guidance on adding recursive types to my implementation using iso-recursive `fold`/`unfold` operators. I have already added in sum, product, record, existential, and universal types.

In System F (w/o type operators), I found it relatively straightforward to do, and I just had a visitor pass through the AST after parsing to perform the fold/unfold isomorphism during case analysis or type construction.

With System F omega, the situation is somewhat more complicated due to the presence of lambda abstractions at the type level. For example (using standard lambda-calc/haskell-ish syntax), lets say I want to define a parameterized `List` datatype

```
datatype List a = Cons a (List a) | Nil
```

This can be encoded in our calculi as (omitting * kinds):

```
type List = μ ΛX::*=>*. ΛA. Cons A (X A) | Nil
substs to: ΛA. Cons A ((μ ΛX::*=>*. ΛA. Cons A (X A) | Nil) A) | Nil
```

But this has issues as soon as we try to unfold the value, since a new abstraction trying to bind `A` again is introduced. This seems like it could work, as long as we are storing the concrete type A somewhere.

Or we can 'lambda drop' it to:

```
type ListF = ΛX. ΛA. Cons (A, X) | Nil
type List  = ΛA. μ (ListF A)
```

The lambda dropping works well for simple recursive types like this, and is straightforward to implement as well, and I can envision a way to automatically generate the `ListF` type. But I have a nagging feeling that something is off about this.

I have been trying to read the literature around this (Mendler-style iteration, Andreas Abel, Ralph Matthes, Tarmo Uustalu, "Iteration and coiteration schemes for higher-order and nested datatypes", etc), but tbh some of it is a bit over my head, and I'm lost as to how to *actually* implement this in a concrete manner. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure I see the issue with mu unfolding to an abstraction. In the first example `List` should unfold to `Cons A ((μ ...) A) | Nil`, not `Cons A (μ ...) | Nil` (i.e., the μ should be applied to an A). Could that be the source of confusion? It definitely makes type checking difficult, but that doesn't seem to be a concern for you, is it?

Comment: That is just a typo when I translated it from code, thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List = μ ΛX. ΛA. Cons A (X A) | Nil
-- μF unfolds to F(μF)
= (ΛX. ΛA. Cons A (X A) | Nil) (μ ΛX. ΛA. Cons A (X A) | Nil)
-- substitute *correctly*
= ΛA. Cons A ((μ ΛX. ΛA. Cons A (X A) | Nil) A) | Nil
--                                           ^ you dropped this!
-- folding back
List = ΛA. Cons A (List A) | Nil
```

The `A` does not need to be "stored" anywhere except the type itself. You dropped the application containing it when it should not have been dropped. Notice that your unfolding is ill-kinded. The second field of the top-level `Cons` has kind `* => *`, but that's not right. But the original was well-kinded, so the unfolding (which should preserve kinds) must have gone wrong.

"Lambda dropping" is fine, but it's not always possible. Consider

```
data Binary a = Leaf a | Branch (Binary (a, a))
```

which contains precisely `2^n` `a`s for some natural `n`. This type is irregularly recursive and cannot be expressed in terms of `μ :: (* => *) => *` as `List` can.

```
type Binary = μ ΛX. ΛA. Leaf A | Branch (X (A, A))
```

Comment: Ah, that's a typo, thanks for catching it. I promise I understand how the substitution works, and have it working in code :).

Comment: Even with the correct substitution there, it is not well formed, because you cannot apply a recursive type to a concrete type, only a type abstraction. 

Let's apply `Nat` to our properly substituted `List` type:
`List = Cons Nat ((μ ΛX. ΛA. Cons A (X A) | Nil) Nat) | Nil`. Nat cannot be substituted into the inner occurences of A, and as such we will have to store `Nat` somewhere so we apply it next time we need to fold.

Comment: I believe that even if you were to modify the typing rules so that you can perform the unfolding isomorphism during type checking (so that you could evaluate `(μ ΛX. ΛA. Cons A (X A) | Nil) Nat`), you would end up in an infinite loop, since you are continually introducing a new type abstraction `ΛA.`. Is this not correct?

Comment: Why would you need to substitute `Nat` in? Just leave the application and let the type of the folding operator deal with it. `fold1_F_A :: F (μ F) A -> μ F A`, and, in particular, `fold1_(ΛX. ΛA. Cons A (X A) | Nil)_Nat :: (Cons Nat ((μ ΛX. ΛA. Cons A (X A) | Nil) Nat) | Nil) -> ((μ ΛX. ΛA. Cons A (X A) | Nil) Nat)`.

Comment: Thanks. I had thought that was another route. Andreas Abel's PhD thesis "A 
 Polymorphic Lambda-Calculus with Sized Higher-Order Types" covers this to some extent as well, sections 3.5 & 4. I think the route you describe (and what the diss. also describes) is what I will likely end up using.